# Running tests on jenkins android emulator

Tags: android, jenkins, android-espresso

I'm setting up a Jenkins server.

I want to build and run my Kespresso test each time I'm pushing on the branch.

I'm using the android emulator jenkins plugin. The emulator starts, then Jenkins build the APK and I launch the connectedAndroidTest.
It launchs tests but I always got this error :

```
09:53:51 > Task :app:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest
09:55:41 Starting 26 tests on hudson_en-US_400_1920x1080_android-24_armeabi-v7a(AVD) - 7.0

ItemCategoryTest > testItemCategoryIntegrity[hudson_en-US_400_1920x1080_android-24_armeabi-v7a(AVD) - 7.0] [31mFAILED [0m
09:56:58    java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Root:
09:56:58    Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@22cb195, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@22cb195, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81e90181 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x1030465 vsysui=0x2000 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81e90181 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x1030465 vsysui=0x2000 needsMenuKey=2}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}}
```

It seems that the view is not found but I don't know why.

If someone has the problem, I'll be glad to get some help

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to run the test from the command line locally on a **newly created** emulator? Maybe there are permission dialogs or something else that blocks the view.

Comment: Hello Alexander,

I have this code to accept permissions : 

`@get:Rule var permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)`

And when I run locally on a new emulator, it works